# Mutex not working in Vista

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 processes running. Both are creating a named mutex with the code

```
Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, "ABC");
```

then both the process use `mut.WaitOne()` and `mut.ReleaseMutex()` to access a shared database file, a number of times in different methods.

This code runs without any problems on XP.

On Vista, I just try to run one process (Process 1) and create the mutex using the same code.
On the line `mut.WaitOne()`, Process 1 goes to sleep permanently.
Notice, by this time I have not even started Process 2.

`mut.WaitOne()` is being called in a method (methodX). 
methodX is called in a loop from another method (methodY).

The structure of methodX is

```
try
{
    mut.WaitOne();
    //do work on the db file
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Also methodY and methodX are both working in a BackgroundWorker. While the code to initialize mutex was called in the main application. 
But, main application never owns the mutex.

---

**Edit**

Here is the code:

```
string mutexName = @"Global\OneComClientDb";
bool mutexWasCreated;
MutexSecurity mSec = new MutexSecurity();
MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(
                         new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                         MutexRights.FullControl,
                         AccessControlType.Allow);
mSec.AddAccessRule(rule);
mut = new Mutex(false, mutexName, out mutexWasCreated, mSec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the two processes running in different sessions?  Have you tried:

```
Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, @"Global\ABC" );
```

Comment: yes i tried that but still the same result .. infact i tried this code..
string mutexName = @"Global\ABC";
                bool mutexWasCreated;
                MutexSecurity mSec = new MutexSecurity();
                MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(
                      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                      MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
                mSec.AddAccessRule(rule);
                mut = new Mutex(false, mutexName, out mutexWasCreated, mSec);

Comment: Is it possible that something else has that mutex open?  Maybe try changing the mutex name or rebooting the computer...

Answer (score 0):

```
string mutexName = @"Global\OneComClientDb";
bool mutexWasCreated;
MutexSecurity mSec = new MutexSecurity();
MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(
      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
      MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
mSec.AddAccessRule(rule);
mut = new Mutex(false, mutexName, out mutexWasCreated, mSec);
```

here is the code